# firebase,can not receive notifications(client side)

Tags: javascript, firebase, notifications, messaging

I have problems with receiving push notifications from firebase server

There is code from firebase-messaging-sw.js file(which uses for receiving)

```
// [START initialize_firebase_in_sw]
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase     libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
'messagingSenderId': 'xxxxxxxxx'
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
// [END initialize_firebase_in_sw]

// If you would like to customize notifications that are received in the
// background (Web app is closed or not in browser focus) then you should
// implement this optional method.
// [START background_handler]
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
// Customize notification here
const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
const notificationOptions = {
body: 'Background Message body.',
icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
};

return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
notificationOptions);
});
// [END background_handler]
```

Subscribe code work 100% fine ,so i will not show it( i need more reputation to add more than 2 links)

There is the server side code Which I use to send notifications:

```
  define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
     $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $priority="high";
        $notification= array('title' => 'Some title','body' => 'hi', "priority" =>"high", );

    $tokens = array('Token-1','token-2');


        $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $tokens,
             'notification' => $notification

            );


        $headers = array(
            'Authorization:key='.API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        // echo json_encode($fields);
       $result = curl_exec($ch);           
       echo curl_error($ch);
       if ($result === FALSE) {
           die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
       }
       curl_close($ch);
       echo  $result;
```

server side also works fine ,because sending notification to firebase ,server returns this response :

{"multicast_id":7642532958945472490,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1490541716147780%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"}]}

as you see ,notification sent successfully.

But i cannot receive it ,i dont see notification window in chrome.

All sources are taken from github examples of firebase.

What is the problem ? Why i can't receive notification? Identifier and access key are correct,no errors or warning in javascript, this is proved by the fact that the notification is sent SUCCESSFULLY

P.S I uses pastebin ,because i can't format code section on stackoverflow,sorry.

thanks

Comment: Please make sure that you include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself. Links take more time to navigate and tend to rot over time. To learn how to format code in a Stack Overflow question, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: ok,in next time i will use stackoverflow formatting .

Comment: I have been edit the question,now ,can you help me ?

Comment: @Giorgi I have the same issue. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @Giorgi Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

At first of all, I recommend you to use something like postman for testing requests. Thereby you can guarantee that the issue is not caused by your code.

i. Do you call this function to specify the service worker for firebase messaging (from your page where you get your registration token)?

```
messaging.useServiceWorker(swRegistration);
```

ii. The firebase example uses only the apiKey for initialization inside the service worker. This caused some problems for me. Instead I'm using the config which is also used in the page:

```
var config = {
   apiKey: "xxxaSyDxxxaQMQW67JxxxnUzxxxSEhVxxxeqKXI",
   authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
   databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
   projectId: "xxx-xxx-xxx",
   storageBucket: "xxx-xxx-xxx.apxxxot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "2xxxx5xxx"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```